# Lines are not showing on line graph when using plot() then lines()

Tags: r, plot

When I'm creating a plot with `plot()` function then using line(), only base plot is showing up.

```
plot(dta$Time, dta$CO2.emissions..kt....India, main = "CO2 Emissions of India & USA", ylab = "", xlab = "TIME", type = "l", col = "blue") 
lines(dta$Time, dta$CO2.emissions..kt....United.States, col = "red", type = "l")
```

In this code only base plot is showing up and not second line.
This is my first using R for making plots, apologies for amatuer mistakes.

I tried adding `legend()` to this plot, which worked well and is shown in the plot.

Comment: After using `plot`, the `ylim`s are set automatically, so if you use `lines` thereafter, they might be simply "off-screen". try specify `ylim=range(c('CO2.emissions..kt....India', 'CO2.emissions..kt....United.States'))` in `plot`.

Comment: Mostly spot-on, but using frame-columns instead of string hints: `ylim = range(c(dta$CO2.emissions..kt....India, dta$CO2.emissions..kt....United.States))` (still in `plot(...)`).

Comment: Thank you.. I made the changes as said it's now showing the desired plot.